# Complexity of prime factor algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, complexity-theory

I just studied how to find the prime factors of a number with [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-prime-factors-of-a-given-number/) algorithm that basically works this way:

```
void printPrimeFactors(N) {

  while N is even
    print 2 as prime factor
    N = N/2

  // At this point N is odd
  for all the ODDS i from 3 to sqrt(N)
    while N is divisible by i
      print i as prime factor
      N = N / i

  if N hasn't been divided by anything (i.e. it's still N)
    N is prime

  }
```

everything is clear but **I'm not sure how to calculate the complexity in big-O of the program above**.

Being the division the most expensive operation (I suppose), I'd say that as a worst-case there could be a maximum of log(N) divisions, but I'm not totally sure of this.

Comment: I would say that the divisible check is the dominant factor, and your worst case is when N is prime. That means you do `sqrt(N)` checks, with all of them returning false.

Comment: Great point, now that you make me think of it. O(sqrt(N)) seems way more reasonable than what I thought

Comment: @biziclop, this particular algorithm is O(sqrt(N)). However, this algorithm is far from optimal. For example, in the main loop on `ODDS i` you can reduce the upper bound from `sqrt(N)` to `sqrt(N / product of known factors)` on every successful iteration.  I'd suggest research "sieves" and related algorithms before implementing.

Comment: @Michael You're right, I assumed that with the update of `N` the upper bound will come down too. Of course the algorithm is still far from optimal even if you carefully adjust your bound and even if you skip known composite numbers (turning the algorithm into the basic Sieve of Erathosthenes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can proceed as like this. First of all, we are only interested in the behavior of the application when `N` is really big. In that case, we can simplify a lot: if two parts have different asymptotic performance, we need only take the one that performs worst.

The first `while` can loop at most `m` times, where `m` is the smallest integer so that 2<sup>m</sup> >= `N`. Therefore it will loop, at worst, log<sub>2</sub>`N` times -- this means that it performs as O(log `N`). Note that the type of log is irrelevant when `N` is large enough.

The `for` loop runs O(sqrt `N`) times. At scale, this is way more massive than log `N`, so we can drop the log.

Finally, we need to evaluate the `while` inside the loop. Since this while loop is executed only for divisors, it will have a big O equal to their number. With a little thought we can see that, at worst, the `while` will loop log<sub>3</sub>`N` times because 3 is the smallest possible divisor.

Thus, the while loop gets executed only O(log `N`) times, but the outer `for` gets executed O(sqrt `N`) times (and often the while loop doesn't run because the current number won't divide).

In conclusion, the part that will take the longest is the `for` loop and this will make the algorithm go as O(sqrt`N`).

Comment: Good explanation. Small nitpick: The number of divisions is in O(sqrt`N`), but the algorithm's runtime complexity is worse due to division for big numbers > O(1).