# Time Complexity Analysis of a function

Tags: c++, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of this following function? I am confused between O(log n) and O(sqrt(n)).

```
map<long long int,long long int> mp;
void PrimeFactorization(long long n)
{
    while(n%2==0)
    {
        n/=2;
        mp[2]++;
    }
    for(long long int i=3;i<=sqrt(n)+1;i+=2)
    {
        while(n%i==0)
        {
            n/=i;
            mp[i]++;
        }
    }
    if(n>2)
    {
        mp[n]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll do better if `mp` was declared as an `unordered_map` instead of as `map`

Comment: and why is that will be better?

Comment: Search, removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity in a `map`. Search, insertion, and removal of elements have average constant-time complexity in an `unordered_map`

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520264/complexity-of-prime-factor-algorithm).

Comment: What Ted said. Because inserts into a sorted `map`  incur O(lg N) insertion time whereas inserts into an unsorted map will incur O(1) insertion time.  The former is usually an implementation of a binary tree. The latter is just a hash table.  It may be moot if you need `mp` to be sorted.

Comment: `O(sqrt(n))`. There are parts of this function that work in `O(log n)` time (those parts can be improved, as previously noted), but `O(sqrt(n))` component dominates.

Comment: Computing `sqrt(n)` on each iteration is wasteful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runs in `O(sqrt(n))`. *Technically*, it's `O(sqrt(n) + log(n)log(log(n)))`, but that `log` factor isn't really that big of a deal (and you can get rid of it by using an unordered map).

Think of the worst case: If `n` is prime, then the loop from 3 up to `sqrt(n)` will just spin all the way up to its limit. This isn't even much of an edge case, since primes are fairly common. Really, the loop is just searching for all the prime factors of `n` anyway, so it will *have* to go up to `sqrt(n)` because that's the limit of the prime factors.

There are other, much faster prime factorization algorithms. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes
and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test